# Как запустить метод через определенное время?

Tags: c#, .net, tpl

Как луче всего запустить один раз метод через определенное время?

То есть нужно вызвать метод через заданное время.

Можно ли это сделать через `Task.Delay()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если ваш метод асинхронный, то да, можно использовать `Task.Delay()`:

```
public async Task MethodWithDelayAsync(int milliseconds)
{
    await Task.Delay(milliseconds);

    // остальной код
}
```

Если код синхронный и вы не хотите использовать async/await, то можете использовать `Timer` из `System.Threading`: устанавливаете задержку и однократный запуск.

```
new Timer(MyMethod, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer.timer(v=vs.110).aspx