# Как запустить функцию в определённое время в C#?

Tags: c#

Делаю сайт на ASP.NET MVC, необходимо сделать так что бы в определённое по часам время, например в 20:20 запустилась определённая функция, в моём случае рассылки почты.

Можно ли это сделать системными средствами или использовать сторонние библиотеки?

Хотелось бы такой функциональности:
По заданному ключу добавляю запуск моей функции на определенное время. Могу много таких функций повесить на разное время. Если надо то могу открепить запуск используя ключ.

Comment: Дубликаты: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460125/10105, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/397208/10105

Comment: @VladD не совсем  - в asp.net туго с долгоживущими потоками, так что решения по ссылкам не подходят.

Comment: @PashaPash: Там есть решения с await, поток по идее не нужен. Но вот если процесс может быть убит, это проблема, конечно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ASP.NET MVC нет надежного способо запустить что-то в определенное время. Нет даже надежного способа запустить что-то в фоновом потоке.

Причина ненадежности - полностью внешнее управление временем жизни приложения. Т.е. если IIS захочет убить или усыпить ваше приложение из-за неактивности пользователей, превышения по памяти, просто по расписанию, по любой другой причине - он убьет. И никакой код, который должен будет отработать в час X - не отработает.

Кроме того, при определенных настройках IIS может запустить два и более одновременных процессов для одного приложения, и ваш код для запуска по расписанию отработает дважды.

Надежные способы:

- Вынести обработку почти в windows service, где можно организовать надежный таймер.
- Вынести обработку почты в console application, поставить его на выполнение в Task Scheduler.
- Оставить обработку почты в ASP.NET / MVC, но привязать ее к определенному url. Сделать простой Windows Service / Console + Task Scheduler / использовать готовые job-ы от вашего хостера для вызова этого url.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Решил использовать вот эту библиотеку - http://hangfire.io/ , при этом гарантии что на 100% отработает во время нету, но мне это думаю не критично uptime сайта будет высокий. Так же думаю попросить хостера сделать настройку что бы приложение сайта не выключалось -  startMode="AlwaysRunning"

Answer (score 0):

А зачем для этого привлекать сайт?
Для таких вещей есть, например, стандартный виндовый Task scheduler, через который запускаете, например, самописную программку

Можно и дальше пофантазировать:

1. Сделать контроллер со спец функциями, который будет вызываться спец. виндовс сервисом и что-нибудь возвращать для анализа. Плюс в том, что весь веб-код в одном проекте.
2. В ApplicationStart приложения вызвать отдельную нитку (thread) с дочерней функцией в которой задать таймер с действием. Не проверял, но в теории должно работать...

Comment: Так я сайт не для этого сделал. Как раз рассылка нужна для сайта.

Comment: возможно поможет, дописал.